# 2D Pictures on 3D Pages in Book Animation are stretching

Tags: texturing, image, uv-image-editor

I am a blender newbie and I'm trying to animate a storybook opening, a few of the pages turning, and then the book closing. I have the animation keyframed, and I have 2D jpeg illustrations that I have placed on the flipping pages, but when added to the Plane models for the pages the 2D jpegs are being stretched (as seen in the photo). I've viewed a lot of tutorials trying to figure out how to fix this, but without any luck unfortunately. If anyone could please give me some guidance or troubleshoot with me, I would greatly appreciate it. [image]

Comment: please provide blend file so we can check it out. your image doesn't help us at all. Maybe you didn't apply scale....could be a lot of reasons.

Comment: What is the best way to provide a blender file? I can create a wetransfer link

Comment: open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=DkWzm8xL" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/DkWzm8xL/)

Comment: please do file -> external data -> pack resources, then save and then upload again, so i can see your textures. Thank you.

Comment: I'm trying to make it less than 30mb to upload. I derezzed my texture assets, but it's still larger than 30mb. Is there another option for sharing?

Comment: Use google or Dropbox or whatever you can access.

Comment: Let me know if this works: https://we.tl/t-ZiaZjbKnHl

Answer (score 0):

*In general you choose quite difficult topic for beginner ...*

---

**First problem** - wrong UVmap

[image]

... fix - "Project from View"

[image]

BTW: As you can see your image is different proportion than the page.

**Second** ... you are stretching page geometry ... your page is not sliding, but is stretch by modifier = it stretching UVmap too.

[image]

### Tips

For cover I use lovely addon **Convert Mesh to Armature** ... by one click it generates rig for you (it starts hierarchy from selected face, so select right side before running operator).

[image]

For deforming page is usually used animated curve object (animated via shape key) ... this object is used for Page object with **Curve modifier**.

[image]

[image]

You can try to rig pages - **Armature with bone type Bendy Bones**.

You can try **Cloth Modifier** [single page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/192079/2214), but that is not your case ... or it works kind of also for [more pages](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/186848/2214) ...

Comment: Thank you! So what is your suggestion to fix the stretching? Do I need to adjust the image dimensions to fit the page dimensions, or is there a way to simply lock the image onto the page plane without it stretching?

Comment: Main problem is not image proportion, but Simple deform modifier type Stretch you use for deformation ... like I wrote you should use animated Curve object to be used as deformer for page (Page object with Curve modofier).

Comment: Thank you! I was able to figure out a solution with your help!

Comment: If the answer solved your issue consider [mark answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) as accepted by clicking on check mark under vote arrows so others can easily see Q was answered from Q list. You can undo it any time.